# How to detect MouseDown event on a datagridview scrollbar?

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

I know how to access the MouseEvents on a normal scroll bar. But how can I detect if a user holds the mouse button on the scroll bar of a datagridview control?

Background: I have my datagridview filled in real time with a lot of data, and auto scroll always to the last entry. When a user now wants to scroll up a little, the auto scroll should wait until the user releases the scroll bar.

Autoscroll code:

```
if (mygrid.Rows.Count > 0)
{
mygrid.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = mygrid.Rows.Count - 1;
}
```

Comment: You could try to get at the event in a mouse hook, I guess but the real question is: would that be good enough or would the scrolling still happen first? Maybe you want to do a check on the cursor position and the mouse button in the mousemove or mouseenter event? How do you implement the autscroll??

Comment: Added the autoscroll code. It's very simple and I just want to add an additional check for a flag which should be set once the user presses mousedown/mouseup.

Comment: When I imagine your program, I wonder: Wouldn't I hate the autoscroll to happen not just when I try to scoll myself but also when I'm on the DGV doing anything else? Like selecting a cell etc.. Consider using the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event to set a `bool dontAutoScroll` flag..

Comment: There is no need to select a cell or something since the grid shows read-only information. Since there is a lot of info, and the grid scrolls rather fast, the user will most likely use the scrollbar to check stuff.

Comment: I see. But still, when 'm reading something I wouldn't want it to be pushed up because something else is being added. I still think that using MouseEnter and MouseLeave would be good and simple event to use..